# java find days in different weeks in month

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want to retrieve the days in the four/five weeks of a month.
For example , If I give input as "Dec 2016" - then I should get days like below

First Week  1 ,2 ,3 ,4
Second Week 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 , 11
Third Week  12,13,14,15,16,17,18
Fourth Week 19,20,21,22,23,24,25
Fifth Week  26,27,28,29

I tried using `calendar` but it is too much of code  - if you have any known solutions  kindly suggest.

I am using java 8 - so if this is possible using Localdate , it would be great

Comment: You may get help if you show what you've tried so far. As it stands now, you're asking to do your job for you.

Comment: Clarify exactly how you define a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution

```
package mypackage;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;


public class DataUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> weeks = new ArrayList<>();

        LocalDate firstDayOfMonth = LocalDate.of(2016, 12 , 1);
        LocalDate firstWeekendOfMonth= firstDayOfMonth.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));

        long firstWeekGap = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(firstDayOfMonth , firstWeekendOfMonth) ;

        String daysInWeek = buildDaysInWeek(1,12,2016);
        weeks.add("{" + daysInWeek +"}");


        for ( int i = ((int)firstWeekGap +1 )  ; i <= 31 ; i = i+7  )
        {
            daysInWeek = buildDaysInWeek(i,12,2016);
            weeks.add("{" + daysInWeek +"}");

        }

        System.out.println(  " weeks " + weeks);


    }

    private static String buildDaysInWeek(int date,int month, int year)
    {
        StringBuffer daysInWeek = new StringBuffer();

        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(year , month , date);

        daysInWeek.append(startDate.getDayOfMonth());

        LocalDate endOfWeek = startDate ;
        while (  endOfWeek.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY )
        {
            endOfWeek = endOfWeek.plusDays(1);
            daysInWeek.append(",");
            daysInWeek.append(endOfWeek.getDayOfMonth());
        }

        return daysInWeek.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Define "week of month"

First you must get clear on what you mean by "week of month". Does week # 1 contain the first of the month? Is so, when does the week end, on a Sunday? A Saturday?

Or is week # 1 the one containing the first Monday? First Sunday?

## `TemporalAdjuster`

The java.time classes include the interface `TemporalAdjuster` for manipulating a date-time object to produce another.

The `TemporalAdjusters` class (note the plural 's') provides several implementations. One is [`dayOfWeekInMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#dayOfWeekInMonth-int-java.time.DayOfWeek-) to answer questions such as "the second Tuesday of this March".

Read the class doc for that adjuster carefully.

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines sensible text representations of date-time values. I suggest you stick to using these rather than make up your own.

So, instead of `Dec 2016`, use `2016-12`.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default. For example, the `YearMonth` class can directly parse and generate values such as `2016-12`.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2016 , 12 );
```

…or, use a [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum object for clarity…

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2016 , Month.DECEMBER );
```

Call `toString` to generate an ISO 8601 formatted string.

> ym:toString(): 2016-12

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse( "2016-12" );
```

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. The `YearMonth` object can give you a `LocalDate` for the first and last day of its month.

## Example

If you define a week-of-month as starting on the 1st and ending on a Sunday, then do something like this. Increment day-by-day, printing each one’s day-of-month number. Test each one’s day-of-week to see if it is the last day of week (by your own definition) and thus needing to wrap to a new line.

You could optimize this code if absolutely necessary. And you may want to clean it up to not print the comma at end. But it gets you going in the right direction.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse( "2016-12" );
LocalDate firstOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 ); 
LocalDate lastOfMonth = ym.atEndOfMonth();
int nthWeek = 1;

LocalDate ld = firstOfMonth;
while( ! ld.isAfter( lastOfMonth ) ) {
    System.out.print( ld.getDayOfMonth() + ", " );
    if( ld.getDayOfWeek().equals( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ) {
        System.out.println( "" ); // Wrap to next line.
    }
    ld = ld.plusDays( 1 );  // Setup for next loop.
}

System.out.println( "\nDone." );
```

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/nf9IAS).

> 1, 2, 3, 4,
>
> 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
>
> 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
>
> 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
>
> 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,
>
> Done.